# What are other options for faster io in Python 2.7

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I have been struggling with [this](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST) practice problem on codechef.com for some time. I was finally able to make a working solution.

```
import sys

def p():
    numbers, div = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())

    ans = 0
    for i in xrange(numbers):
        if int(sys.stdin.readline()) % div == 0:
            ans += 1
        i += 1

    print ans

p()
```

But this executed in 43.60 as is shown [here](http://www.codechef.com/status/INTEST,anshbansal). It is much worse than the best given solutions. They are all using psyco module which is not working for Python 2.7.

Is there some faster method of IO in Python 2.7 which can improve the time-efficiency of this practice problem and in general programming problems requiring huge inputs? Please also consider the cases when memory use may be increased for getting desired time-efficiency.

EDIT:

Faster IO for floating point numbers is not required for this problem but it may be required for some other problem so suggest something for them also.

EDIT2:

```
nums = int(sys.stdin.readline())
float_nums = map(float,next(sys.stdin).split())
for p in islice(sys.stdin, float_nums, None):
```

I was using something like the above for use with @Martijn Pieters answer for floating point numbers. I am not using `xrange()`

Comment: The `i += 1` is entirely redundant and essentially a noop in this code.

Comment: You could experiment with reading a larger chunk of input, and then splitting it into lines.

Comment: @ThomasK I am new to Python so any hints would be useful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My mistake. What's a noop?

Comment: @Zel `no-op` stands for no-operation. An operation that does nothing, but simply consumes some time.

Comment: @Bakuriu So the i+= 1 is 'noop' because i is updated next via the generator xrange() in the very next statement. Correct?

Comment: Yes. The operation is useless, but it's still executed and consumes CPU-time.

Comment: When you browse the solutions on that site, you can tell apart the PsyCo solutions from their use of over 36 M of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the file as an iterator (different, potentially more optimal buffer strategy), and take advantage of generator expressions:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

def p():
    numbers, div = map(int, next(sys.stdin).split())
    print sum(int(l) % div == 0 for l in islice(sys.stdin, numbers))    

p()
```

This treats booleans as integers (they are a subclass; `True` is 1 in an integer context, `False` is 0).

Or try:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

def p():
    numbers, div = map(int, next(sys.stdin).split())
    print sum(1 for l in islice(sys.stdin, numbers) if int(l) % div == 0)    

p()
```

These do different amounts of work, and depending on the amount of divisible numbers present, one could be faster than the other (`if` tests  versus summing 0s and 1s).

Comment: `sum(int(l) % div == 0 for l in islice(sys.stdin, numbers))` might be a little better (avoids the `if`)

Comment: @Volatility From simple benchmarks it seems using the `if` is about 20-30% *faster*. Keep in mind that in python an `if` doesn't cost much, while adding a number produces various function calls and hence a lot of overhead. It's better to branch and avoid extra addition calls then to avoid branching but always performing an addition.

Comment: Am I missing something? Where is the `if`?

Comment: @Zel: I changed the answer; will give you both alternatives in a few sec.

Comment: [Failed](http://www.codechef.com/status/INTEST,anshbansal) Your solution did not work. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @Zel You probably forgot to `import sys`

Comment: My mistake, sorry. It improved the time to 31.79

Comment: This solution does not work in case of floating point numbers.

Comment: For floats, you need a tolerance level for how close to 0 you want to get. It'll work, but you need to rework the `== 0` test.

Comment: @Zel The problem description states that the numbers are integers.

Comment: @JanneKarila You are correct but I didn't ask the question specifically for solving this practice problem. My question is faster Python IO for improving IO efficiency. I updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: @Zel If you are reading floats you simply use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: @JanneKarila I tried that. When I used that I got the error `ValueError: Indices for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= maxint`

Comment: @Zel: You are interpreting the number count (first line) as float, and `xrange()` won't take floats; that makes no sense.

Comment: @Zel: Also, if you are interested in performant IO, then my answer helped you; it doesn't matter what you then *do* with the read data. Converting to `float()` *or* `int()` is an after-the-fact problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please see EDIT2 of question. I was using the generator as the loop.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you tried but that makes **no sense**. You are reading the number count and divisor. Don't interpret the number count as a float.

Comment: But you *started* your question about I/O speeds; don't change it to be about trying to shoehorn in floats where they don't fit. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have been using this solution for sometime. Maybe I missed something. Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258890/why-does-runtime-error-occur-in-this-code/17259103?noredirect=1#comment25015611_17259103

Answer (score 1):

Use [pypy](http://pypy.org/), a successor to pysco.

Comment: Except CodeChef doesn't support PyPy.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters... ouch, hadn't thought of that.