# What causes the NZEC (Non Zero Exit Code) error in my Sums in a Triangle solution?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was doing [this practice problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/SUMTRIAN) on codechef. I have already [solved this in C](http://www.codechef.com/status/SUMTRIAN,anshbansal) and was trying to do the same in Python 2.7. I am getting NZEC error on codechef judge which is "Non Zero Exit Code". I don't understand why this could be happening. The program is working fine on my computer. What kind of corner case can be giving this problem?

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

def p(): 
    cases = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    for case in xrange(cases):
        height = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        triangle = [map(int, i.split()) for i in islice(sys.stdin,height)]

        prev_row = triangle[0]
        for i in xrange(1, height):
            cur_row = triangle[i]

            cur_row[0] += prev_row[0]
            cur_row[len(cur_row) - 1] += prev_row[len(prev_row) - 1]

            for j in xrange(1, len(cur_row) - 1):
                if(prev_row[j - 1] > prev_row[j]):
                    cur_row[j] += prev_row[j - 1]
                else:
                    cur_row[j] += prev_row[j]

            prev_row = cur_row

        print max(prev_row)

p()
```

Comment: It seems that this is codechef peculiarity. this has nothing with python itself

Comment: @aksam You should probably look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244522/regarding-specific-edit

Comment: @aksam, please do not add superfluous tags to questions. This is not a runtime error, as noted by oleg, Martijn, and Aseem himself in the question ("The program is working fine on my computer.") See the edit I've made for an example of what sorts of changes would've been appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix using the file object as an iterator, and calling `.readline()` on the object.

By using `islice()` on `sys.stdin` you are treating the object as an iterator, calling `file.next()` under the hood. From the [`.next()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next):

> In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()` with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right.

The solution is to not use `.readline()` *or* not to use the file object as iterator. In this case, use `next(sys.stdin)` instead of `sys.stdin.readline()` to consistently use the object as an iterator. That is more efficient than using `.readline()` in any case:

```
def p(): 
    cases = int(next(sys.stdin))
    for case in xrange(cases):
        height = int(next(sys.stdin))
        triangle = [map(int, i.split()) for i in islice(sys.stdin, height)]
```

or even:

```
def p(): 
    for case in xrange(int(next(sys.stdin))):
        triangle = [map(int, i.split()) for i in islice(sys.stdin, int(next(sys.stdin)))]
```

Comment: This makes more sense. How did you know that calling islice calls file.next() under the hood? How could I know? I have read a portion of the official Python tutorial. Should I start reading the library reference also? Because practice alone isn't helping me a lot.

Comment: @Zel: `islice()` and other iteration tools (the whole `itertools` module, for example) work with [iterator types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter); the Python API for iterator types is well defined. The [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) is the standard function to call on iterators to get their next value; it works better than calling `fileobj.next()` because in Python 3, the latter has been renamed to `.__next__()`.

Comment: Actually I was asking for advice on how could I know more without asking on SO everytime...

Comment: @Zel: The Python tutorial covers iterators in [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) of the classes chapter.

Comment: @Zel: Don't worry about asking this kind of stuff! Iterators are relatively advanced programming magic. I do not expect people to know and grok this immediately.

Comment: Can you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501275/faster-io-giving-slower-results-in-this-specific-situation). Mixing both is giving me faster results and no problems and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I don't know why it is faster, but *first* using `.readline()`, *then* using the file as an iterator works because it is using the file as an iterator that creates the iteration buffer that means `.readline()` reads the wrong lines. So the problem is that you should not use `.readline()` *after* using the file object as an iterator, at least not without doing a `.seek()` first to reset the position and the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
triangle = [map(int, i.split()) for i in islice(sys.stdin,height)]
```

to this:

```
triangle = [map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()) for _ in xrange(height)]
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next):

> As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()`
>   with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right.

```
#so.py
import sys
from itertools import islice
print list(islice(sys.stdin,3))
print sys.stdin.readline()
```

Demo:

```
$ python so.py <abc
['2\n', '3\n', '1\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 4, in <module>
    print sys.stdin.readline()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Comment: I am new to Python so I am having problem trying to understand the difference it produces. Can you explain?

Comment: Ok this solution worked but I didn't get why I cannot use islice on sys.stdin? I have used this before and it worked fine. Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17023273/2235567

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree that comment was buggy(now removed), But I did [mention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258890/why-does-runtime-error-occur-in-this-code/17259103?noredirect=1#comment25015813_17259103) afterwards that `islice` can be used but can't be mixed with `readline()`,`read()` etc. Though thanks for the `seek()` tip, learned something new today. :)

Comment: Yup, saw that; cleaned out my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Codechef FAQ :

http://www.codechef.com/wiki/faq#Why_do_I_get_an_NZEC

Comment: I corrected the question about the full form of NZEC. That still doesn't answer my question.