# Faster IO giving slower results in this specific situation

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

To read in integers fastly I have been using

```
cases = int(next(sys.stdin))
```

instead of the slower

```
cases = int(sys.stdin.readline())
```

I have been getting better timing in every problem I used this but in case of [this SPOJ problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/) and [the same codechef problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/ONP) I got better results using the second instead of first. I don't have any idea why this happened.

What is the reason that the 2nd method suddenly became faster compared to the 1st method for this specific problem?

Here are the [Timing results of SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/status/ONP,anshbansal/) and [timing results of codechef](http://www.codechef.com/status/ONP,anshbansal?sort_by=All&sorting_order=asc&language=4&status=15&Submit=GO)

The 2 complete code that I used are

```
import sys
from itertools import islice
def p():
    cases = int(next(sys.stdin))
    string = [i[:len(i) -1] for i in islice(sys.stdin, cases)]
    for i in string:
        ops, ans = [], []
        for c in i:
            if c in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']:
                ops.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                ans.append(ops.pop())
            elif c == '(':
                pass
            else:
                ans.append(c)

        print ''.join(ans)

p()
```

and the second one is

```
import sys
from itertools import islice
def p():

    cases = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    string = [i[:len(i) -1] for i in islice(sys.stdin, cases)]
    for i in string:
        ops, ans = [], []
        for c in i:
            if c in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']:
                ops.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                ans.append(ops.pop())
            elif c == '(':
                pass
            else:
                ans.append(c)

        print ''.join(ans)

p()
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com, the question is off-topic here. And use `timeit` module to check the timings of your programs.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I know that the first method of reading input **is** faster. I have checked in many problems on online judges. There is something specifically with this problem's solution that I am overlooking that is giving this contradiction. Hence it isn't off-topic. Because this question deals with `a specific programming problem` which is explicitly mentioned in [what can be asked](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have enough data on the SPOJ timings. The codechef timings all look too close to call to me.

Any timing difference between *one* `.readline()` call and *one* `next()` call are going to come down to differences in swap availability, other processes running on the machine, I/O flushes, etc. In other words, **not** to any actual performance differences between the two approaches.

You'll have to do your own timings, on your own machine, against thousands of runs to be able to figure out if one is actually faster than the other.

Comment: On SPOJ the timings of `0.10` is for the 2nd code and timing `0.19` is for the 1st code. You are correct about codechef timings being too close. I am working on how to do proper timings by giving various test inputs. It is taking some time. I'll update when I am able to use `timeit` module properly and learn how to write unit tests properly.

Comment: You ran each problem on SPOJ **once**. You cannot read anything much in the timings. Also, do you know the **exact** setup SPOJ uses? OS, kernel parameters, Python version? We are talking about I/O speed here, where the OS is more of a factor than Python is.

Comment: Python version is `2.7`. The machine is Pyramid mentioned [here](http://www.spoj.com/clusters/). I agree that isn't enough. Even if I knew the OS I don't know what can be its effect here.

Comment: Was there some burnination of tags going on due to which `codechef` was removed?

Comment: Yes, all programming contest tags have been burninated. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler